# Script for separating series of photos

Tags: python

I need to visually separate photos (JPEGs) in a folder by placing black placeholder pictures between series with identical file names (only last two digits of the file names are different). The folder is typically containing single (stand alone) photos, named something like 03-12345-randomfilename.jpg and series named 03-12345-file01.jpg, 03-12345-file02.jpg, ..03, ..04, etc.

The singles should be left alone, but I need to place a black picture before and after all series.

I have the following Python script (originally written by someone else) that is intermittently failing for no apparent reason. It usually works, but sometimes it will overwrite files in the middle of a series, or more typically, it will fail to place a black picture after the last photo in a series. I've spent hours trying to figure out what's going on, but I'm stuck.

Any suggestions most appreciated.

```
def blackJPG(directory):
    # iterate over every file name in the directory
    blackJPG = '/Users/username/black.jpg'

    filelist = {}
    for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)
        stringmatch = re.compile(r'(\d{2})(.*?)(\d+)(.*?)(([A-Za-z]+))(.*?)(\d+)')
        m = stringmatch.search(file_name)

        #Create search table
        if m:
            sequence = int(m.group(8))
            filename_without_sequence = "{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}".format(m.group(1),m.group(2),m.group(3),m.group(4),m.group(6),m.group(7))
            filelist.update({filename_without_sequence: (sequence)})

    for key, value in filelist.iteritems():
        if value > 1:
            newJPG = "{0}/{1}00.jpg".format(directory, key)

            if value >= 10:
                lastJPG = "{0}/{1}{2}.jpg".format(directory, key, value+1)
            else:
                lastJPG = "{0}/{1}0{2}.jpg".format(directory, key, value+1)

            #Create first blackJPG
            shutil.copyfile(blackJPG, newJPG)

            #Create last blackJPG
            shutil.copyfile(blackJPG, lastJPG)

    return "Done"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variation is always the last 2 characters, then you can grab the part that doesn't change (the prefix) count the number of prefixes and create a file for those with more than one file:

```
def add_black_jpg(directory):
    series_count = {}
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        name, ext = os.path.splitext(file)
        prefix = name[:-2]
        count = series_count.get(prefix, 0)
        series_count[prefix] = count + 1

    for prefix, count in series_count.items():
        if count > 1:
            shutil.copyfile(black_jpg_location, f"{prefix}00.jpg")
```